# The REST API does not work in Node.js&Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am creating a simple CRUD bulletin board using Express.

I want to do something like the following when a request comes in.

```
get /board/:id => show action
patch /board/:id => update action
delete /board/:id => delete action
```

But I do all the /board/:id requests with show action.

What's wrong with me?

**routes**

```
router.get("/:id", board.show);
router.patch("/:id", board.update);
router.delete("/:id", board.delete);
```

**edit view**

```
...
<form action=`/board/${board._id}` method="patch">
...
```

Comment: what is your `board.show` function? where have you mounted your router?

Comment: The board.show function is handled by router.get ('/ :id', board.show). Board.findById is defined. and res.render('show')

Comment: Can you clarify in your question what the issue is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form tag does not support method patch. It has to be either get or post https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp